# Finding a differentiable function that cannot be bounded by quadratic function

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that it's value at $0$ is $0$ and its derivative at $0$ is also $0$ and can never be bounded by any form of quadratic function in any neighborhood of the origin?

I have been thinking about this for a long time but got no clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}$?

It satisfies your condition, but $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2} = \infty$, so $f(x)$ is larger than $cx^2$ near $x=0$ for every $c>0$.

(You may have another kind of "bound" in mind though.)

Comment: Let $p(x)=x^2+99$. Much bigger than $f$ near $0$.

Comment: @user188201 Yes, that was what my caveat was for. (And if we allow constants, the question is trivial. By continuity at $0$, $f$ must be bounded near $x=0$, so just a large constant will do.)

Comment: Absolutely great. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's true whenever $f$ is twice differentiable at $0$.

In that case, $$\displaystyle f(x)=f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)=f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\epsilon(x^2)$$ where $\epsilon$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$

Consequently, there exists some $\delta >0$ such that $|x|\leq \delta\implies |\epsilon(x^2)|\leq \left|\frac{f''(0)}{4}\right| $

Reverse triangular inequality implies $|f(x)|\geq \left|\frac{f''(0)}{4}\right|x^2$ whenever $ |x|\leq \delta$.